# how to debug virtual variable translator.load()

Tags: qt, qml

no matter what i try, the translator wont load the translation file and keeps showing only ids instead of the translation

i have triad everything i could posibly google up

```
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QtQml>
#include <QTranslator>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

QTranslator translator;
translator.load(QLocale(), "c:/asteroid/asteroid-sporttracking-master", ".", "i18n", ".gm");
app.installTranslator(&translator);

return app.exec();
}
```

the full path for the translation file is:
c:\asteroid\asteroid-sporttracking-master\i18n\asteroid-sportapp.en_GB.ts
 - there are files with multipla local() -en_GB/cs/etc

so is there a way to console.log() the virtual variable created by translator.load()?

Comment: Check Qtranslator.load returned value at least.

Comment: Shouldn't you load the translator as early as possible, before initializing your engine?

Comment: fobilis: thats what im trying to figure out, how to check the returned value translator.load() makes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after all I found out the file with translation must be in directory where the debugger will compile the executable file, not with the code directory

Comment: Have you tried my example? "QApplication::applicationDirPath" solve you problem.

Comment: actually not :(

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing QM and TS Files. You need to use lupdate and lrelease tools. lupdate to create and update the TS files and then lrelease to generate QM files. The application will use QM files.

In your code the path and filename has to be entered because the system didn't find the QM Files but Isn't a good idea using absolute path. Please see my example:

```
String filename = QString("app.qm");
QString path = QApplication::applicationDirPath();

if(translator.load(path + filename)){
        qApp->installTranslator(&translator);
}
```